# Input to non-active window

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following Visual Basic 2010 code:

```
Function GetScreenPixel(ByVal Location As Point) As Color
    Dim C As Color
    Using Bmp As New Bitmap(1, 1)
        Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp)
            G.CopyFromScreen(Location, Point.Empty, Bmp.Size)
            C = Bmp.GetPixel(0, 0)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return C
End Function
```

To get the color of a pixel on the screen.

I then use something like:

```
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" Alias "mouse_event" (ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cButtons As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If GetScreenPixel(New Point(650, 728)).ToString = "Color [A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]" Then
        Cursor.Position = New Point(955, 548)
        mouse_event(&H2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        mouse_event(&H4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

To get whether a certain button on the screen is shown and active (if true then the pixel 650, 728 will be white), and if so, it will click it.

This works fine. My question is, if I can somehow extend the code so that both the function to get the pixel color, and the code to click the mouse can be applied to a non-active window. So that I can leave my application running and clicking the button whenever it is necessary and I can also use my computer for other things at the same time.

I've heard about something called:

```
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
```

However I have had a lot of difficulty getting it to work with the sample code I have shown above - and it still doesn't provide a solution to getting a pixel's color on a non-active window.

Thanks.

Comment: No one has a solution? Or even a hint at how to tackle the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In order to **activate other window** it is necessary to have **sleep** between Mouse DOWN & UP to simulate real click

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE,
     (uint)Convert.ToInt32(position.X * (65535.0 / System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width)),
    (uint)Convert.ToInt32(position.Y * (65535.0 / System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)), 0, 0);

Thread.Sleep(400);

mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE,
     (uint)Convert.ToInt32(position.X * (65535.0 / System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width)),
    (uint)Convert.ToInt32(position.Y * (65535.0 / System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)), 0, 0);
```

Also you might be interested in mouse move function - positions should be set with MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE flag in a range 0 - 65535

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE,
                    (uint)Convert.ToInt32(position.X * (65535.0 / System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width)),
                    (uint)Convert.ToInt32(position.Y * (65535.0 / System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)), 0, 0);
```

Comment: My intention wasn't to activate another window though mouse clicks; I have already been able to do this. What I wanted was a way of sending virtual input to a window which isn't active (without activating it, and disrupting whatever else I am doing).